# Is ssl_dhparam necessary for nginx when client use the cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256

Tags: ssl, nginx, encryption

In Nginx I set `ssl_ciphers` as **DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256** and send a https request by openssl command `"openssl s_client -connect 1.1.1.1:443 -cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 -state"`.
There is one error log in nginx says

> "484815 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408A0C1:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher) while SSL handshaking
>   ".

So I add `ssl_dhparam dhparam.pem` in **nginx.conf.** The `dhparam.pem` is generated by ***openssl***.

This time no error appeared.

I'm confused if the `dhparam` file is necessary when nginx need to support the DHE cipher.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I feel this question would be a little more readable if you were to seperate out the code.

Comment: Yes. ciphersuites using DHE keyexchanges in OpenSSL require 'tmp_DH' parameters, [which the `ssl_dhparam` directive provides](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_dhparam) . The same is true for DH_anon keyexchange, but in practice nobody uses those.